# How to type a long/em dash `—`

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, internationalization

When writing emails and articles I often find myself in the need to use a long/em dash `—` character, not to be confused with the hyphen `-` character. Normally what I end up doing is I type two consecutive hyphens `--` and hit the `Space` key, which then ends up replacing the two hyphens with the long dash.

However, when posting articles in browser-based editors this doesn't always work — such as with the post editor here — so I have to type the double hyphen + `Space` elsewhere, like in a dummy email, copy the long dash from there and paste it here. This is very inconvenient of course.

I'd like a shortcut to enter the long dash character directly.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This might be one of those that changes by language, but on a UK English keyboard [& from comments, also US English], there are 4 dashes available from the key to the right of 0, Minus.

-  <kbd>-</kbd>  key alone (hyphen)
–  <kbd>-</kbd>    <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  (en dash)
—  <kbd>-</kbd>    <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  (em dash)
_  <kbd>-</kbd>    <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  (underscore)

*Late Edit...*
To complete the set, & from comments...

<kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>-</kbd>  will give 'information separator one' which looks like a space "" & doesn't even seem to print in here. You could, however use the keyboard replacement tool to turn that into a true minus sign...  −

[image]

Comment: This is true on the American English keyboard as well.

Comment: To complete the standard quartet, is there a way to type U+2212 MINUS SIGN (−) without the manual Unicode input method?

Comment: @wchargin for U+2212 you have to use character viewer or unicode hex input.  Do you really have a need for that?  Is there a problem using the ascii version available on every keyboard, which is called "hyphen-minus".

Comment: @TomGewecke: Yeah, I use U+2212 all the time. One benefit is that “+” and “−” are the same width (in any good font). It’s also just semantically the right thing to do—for the same reason that you wouldn’t typeset an em dash as three consecutive hyphens.

Comment: @wchargin - I added a method to complete your 'set' :)

Answer (score 11):

After some digging around I've found that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Minus</kbd> renders the long/em dash (—) character.

Comment: I was about to write an answer, but discovered that though I can set all 4 dashes in here as comments - – — _ that in the answer space the n-dash – & m-dash — were coming out as the same character.

Comment: & yet once posted, it corrects itself. Odd.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's because the monospace font renders `–` and `—` identically.

Comment: Macs do not have Alt keys. The key you are looking for is Option.

Comment: @GlenYates Don't be so hasty: Every Mac keyboard I've owned has 'alt' on it. The beige ones use to have Option written as well as alt, but that was phased out. It may depend on region/language layout.

Comment: @GlenYates, I don't want to start an endless debate on how the darn key should be called, but mine is a British keyboard and it reads `alt` so that's what I call it. Maybe yours says `Option` but you still understood well enough what I meant.

Comment: @GlenYates - all Mac keyboards except the US ANSI & some Asian keyboards say 'alt' these days [& for at least 10 years] - ref: https://support.apple.com/HT201794 The terms have long been interchangeable.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think that support doc may be out of date. The pics for Magic Keyboards all show only option. See for example https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLA22FC/A/magic-keyboard-french

Comment: @TomGewecke - Looks like they may be swinging back towards opt then - all the keyboards in the building here say alt, but tbh I don't let it bother me ;)

Comment: I will concede that my only experience is with US Apple keyboards, but every single one of them has said Option. More importantly, the documentation (and I've used Macs since System 6) has referred to the key as the Option key. Also the developer documentation going back to Inside Macintosh Volume I, refers to it as such.

Comment: The US-layout 2013 MacBook Pro I have, and I believe the two I had before it, have _both_ Alt and Option on that key. (: (The support article Tetsujin mentioned matches my keyboard.) But I don't have any experience with newer keyboards, so they might have changed it since then.